# Inserting code into a Tkinter window with a Class type format

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I am having difficulty putting the following code into a tkinter window that has a class format.
The code in its current form reads data from an Arduino board and continuously plots it onto two separate graphs. I am interested in putting it into a Tkinter GUI so that I can manipulate the data and ultimately add new functions and build up the application.

All I am looking to do is have this code function the way it does but reformatted so that it fits into a Tkinter window with Classes.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import gridspec
import plotly.plotly as py
connected = False

comPort = 'COM4'

ser = serial.Serial(comPort, 9600) #sets up serial connection (make sure baud rate is correct - matches Arduino)

while not connected:
    serin = ser.read()
    connected = True


plt.ion()                    #sets plot to animation mode

length = 10                 #determines length of data taking session (in data points)
x = [0]*length               #create empty variable of length of test
y = [0]*length
z = [0]*length

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(7, 7)                #sets up grid space
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])              #determines location of graph
ax1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)     #Hides x,y axis
ax1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax1.set_ylim([1,30])                        #this is how to set the yaxis
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,5])              #determines location of graph
ax2.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax2.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

ax2.set_ylim([1,30])


xline, = ax1.plot(x)         #sets up future lines to be modified
yline, = ax2.plot(y)

for i in range(10000):     #while you are taking data
    data = ser.readline()    #reads until it gets a carriage return. MAKE SURE THERE IS A CARRIAGE RETURN OR IT READS FOREVER
    sep = data.split()      #splits string into a list at the tabs


    x.append(int(sep[0]))   #add new value as int to current list
    y.append(int(sep[0]))


    del x[0]
    del y[0]


    xline.set_xdata(np.arange(len(x))) #sets xdata to new list length .. code works without this
    yline.set_xdata(np.arange(len(y)))


    xline.set_ydata(x)                 #sets ydata to new list
    yline.set_ydata(y)


    plt.pause(0.001)                   #in seconds
    plt.show()                         #draws new plot

ser.close() #closes serial connection (very important to his into the cmd line to close the connection)
```

Comment: I suggest trying to reformat it yourself, and then come back here with a specific question if you get stuck. As written this is a bit too broad since you're asking us to rewrite your code for you.

Comment: To be more specific. Is there a certain or general template that can be followed when converting code into Tkinter?